# How do I append text to a file with vim script?

Tags: vim

I want a function to append text to a file (not a buffer) in vim. As far as I can see, there is no `appendfile()`. But the desired functionality can be emulated with `readfile()` and `writefile()`:

```
fu! TQ84_log (S)

   let l:f = readfile('my.log')
   call add(l:f, a:S)
   call writefile(l:f, 'my.log')

endfu
```

Since `my.log` can grow quite large, I'd rather not read and write the entire file when I want to add a line. So, I came up with another "solution":

```
fu! TQ84_log (S)
   silent execute "!echo " . a:S . ">> my.log"    
endfu
```

This works (on windows, that is) as expected. Yet, when I invoke `TQ84_log()`, that `cmd.exe` window pops up for a short time. This is a bit distracting.

Is there a better solution for my problem?

Comment: If you do not find an alternative, you can avoid the cmd.exe window with [shell.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3123).

Comment: You should use `function` instead of `fu` and use more readable variable names. If you don't do that for others at least do that for yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to `:help writefile()`:

```
When {flags} contains "a" then append mode is used, lines are
appended to the file: >
    :call writefile(["foo"], "event.log", "a")
    :call writefile(["bar"], "event.log", "a")
```

Comment: That was added in 7.4.503, released 2014-11-05 according to https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v7.4.503, a few months after my answer. Still, good to know and worth an up-vote.

Comment: [https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#writefile%28%29](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#writefile%28%29)

Answer (score 18):

If you have a range of lines in your current buffer that you want to append to the log file, then

```
:[range]w >> my.log
```

does exactly what you want.  (Well, maybe not exactly.  For example, it has the side effect of making `my.log` the alternate file, and if you plan to use `:e#` or something, it may mess you up.)

If you already have the log message in a variable, then you could open up a scratch buffer, use `append()` or `:put` to add the line(s) to your scratch buffer, then `:w >> my.log` and close the scratch buffer.

```
:help special-buffers
:help :put
:help :w
```

Here is a complete log function.  There is room for improvement:  the combination of `:new` and `:q` may not restore the layout if you have split windows, and `:put` on an empty buffer leaves you with a blank line that you probably do not want.

```
function! Mylog(message, file)
  new
  setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=hide noswapfile nobuflisted
  put=a:message
  execute 'w >>' a:file
  q
endfun
```

Comment: This is perfect, Now I can write to my FIFO easy peasy. I use a fifo to pass text to another computer via ssh.